# Error handling of a Custom Form Handler in ATG

Tags: java, atg

I am new to ATG. And I am trying to use RepositoryFormHandler of my own. But I am not able to do the validations on the form.

Here is my .java file:

```
public class MyLoginBean extends RepositoryFormHandler {

    private String logname;
    private String logpwd;
    private String message;

    public String getLogname() {
        return logname;
    }

    public void setLogname(String logname) {
        this.logname = logname;
    }

    public String getLogpwd() {
        return logpwd;
    }

    public void setLogpwd(String logpwd) {
        this.logpwd = logpwd;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean handleLogname(DynamoHttpServletRequest pRequest,
            DynamoHttpServletResponse pResponse) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        boolean tf=true;
        if(logname.isEmpty() || logname==null)
        {
            tf=false;
            setMessage("User name can't empty");
        }

        System.out.println("inside logname");
        return tf;
    }

    public void handleFormException(DropletFormException exception,
            DynamoHttpServletRequest request, DynamoHttpServletResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleFormException(exception, request, response);
    }

}
```

And here is my .jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/dspTaglib" prefix="dsp" %>
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ErrorMessageForEach"/>
<dsp:importbean bean="/dynamusic/MyLoginBean"/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Custom Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<dsp:form style="color:white">
    <table style="background:#3b5998">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <dsp:droplet name="ErrorMessageForEach">
                        <dsp:param bean="MyLoginBean.formExceptions" name="exceptions"/>
                        <dsp:oparam name="output">
                            <li>
                                <dsp:valueof param="message"/>
                            </li>
                        </dsp:oparam>
                    </dsp:droplet>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dsp:input type="text" name="logname" bean="MyLoginBean.logname"> </dsp:input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dsp:input type="password" name="logpwd" bean="MyLoginBean.logpwd"> </dsp:input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dsp:input type="submit" bean="MyLoginBean.login"> </dsp:input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</dsp:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is all I've tried so far and still trying something else.**
Please suggest the solution for it and also tell me the mistakes, if any, in the code pasted here.

Comment: Your accessor to `logname` will conflict with your `handleLogname` method as both of these will be referred to by the form as `MyLoginBean.logname`. Looks like you subsequently fixed this by having `MyLoginBean.login` on the JSP but without a related `handle` method in the Java code. Also see Patrick's comments for more guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Don't override handleFormException
2. Instead of using setMessage, use ATG's built-in behavior.  All form handlers inherit a Vector of form exceptions from the GenericFormHandler superclass.  To add an error, use:

`addFormException(new DropletException("Your error message"));`

Then, at the end of your method, call:

`return checkFormRedirect(getSuccessUrl(), getFailUrl(), pRequest, pResponse);`

This checks if any form exceptions have been added, and if so, redirects to the failUrl, otherwise redirects to the successUrl.

3. By convention, you should name your form handler *FormHandler, for example ProfileFormHandler, BillingInfoFormHandler, PaymentInfoFormHandler etc.

Hope this helps.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22630_01/Platform.1002/apidoc/atg/droplet/GenericFormHandler.html#getFormExceptions()